# angular-fontawesome 5 icons with primeng 7 or Angular 2+

Tags: angular, font-awesome, primeng, angular7, font-awesome-5

I have followed the instructions to use svg icons of angular-fontawesome 5 icons. Please find the link below

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome

As a **first step**

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core 
npm i  --save @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome
```

If I am correct to use the brand icons

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
```

**Step two:** In app.module.ts file: Imported the following

```
import {FontAwesomeModule} from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import {fab, faFacebookSquare, faGoogle} from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
```

**Step three:** As per the primeng documentation I want to use the brand icons inside the button.

```
<div class="center-text">
 <p-button icon="fab fa-google" label="Click"></p-button> 
</div>
```

No errors in the console. But couldnt see the icon in display.

As an alternative way:

```
  <div class="center-text">
  <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
   <p-button label="Click"></p-button>
  </div>
```

Still no output. Kindly help how to bring the brand icons inside the primeng buttons.

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to. Everywhere in the documentation you link, they are creating icons through their component `fa-icon`, so as you have above it would be `<fa-icon [icon]="faGoogle" ></fa-icon>`

Comment: You can find a more complete example how to do this [here](https://github.com/PdUi/stack-overflow-answer-repos/tree/master/ng-fontawesome/projects/ng-fa/src/lib).

Comment: @peinearydevelopment Thanks for this I have now used the <fa-icon> tag. I could see the icon coming up on the screen but how do you push inside the button.

Comment: I don't believe you can. As you can see if you look in the dev tools, that `fa-icon` html element gets replaces with an svg. I think you would have to have the button surrounding the icon.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment sorry quite confused. In the dev tools I could see the svg element. But the button tag is outside of SVG.

Answer (score 4):

To use Font Awesome together with PrimeNG you need to use the standard fontawesome package, not angular-fontawesome.

```
npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

And in your angular.json file:

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css",
    ...
],
```

See **https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=56786** for more information.

Comment: Thanks. The way you have mentioned is loading all icons. Which will increase the bundle size. Also I am looking for brand icons only not all the icons

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help someone for sure. The following steps will help you to load only the icons that you want.

Assuming you want to use only brand icons

**Step 1:**

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core 
npm i  --save @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome
```

**Step 2:**

In app.module.ts under imports

[image]

Also, add the following code at the top of the module. Overall it will look like below

```
import {FontAwesomeModule} from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
library.add(fab);
```

**Step 3:** In app.module.ts constructor:

```
constructor(private library: FaIconLibrary) {
    library.addIcons(
        faStackOverflow,
        faGithub,
        faMedium,
        faLinkedinIn,
    );
}
```

Step 4: In app.module, under imports

```
import {
    FaIconLibrary,
    FontAwesomeModule,
} from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import {
    faStackOverflow,
    faGithub,
    faMedium,
    faLinkedinIn
} from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
```

**Step 5:** To test in app.component.html.   using github as an example

```
<a href="https://www.snatchexcel.com/" target="_blank">
  <fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'github' [spin]="true" ]"></fa-icon> 
</a>
```

Run it using `ng s` to see your changes.